# Getting changes based on uploaded time

Tags: android, git, gerrit

I am using the following ssh command to get all the changes on project "platform/vendor/company-proprietary/code" and branch "master" that are in open status,this gives a large volume of data and some unnecessary changes to integrate, I am looking to control this.

1. has anyone used a similar command to get changes and sort by the uploaded time or
2. get changes based on a specified upload time
3. Any other ideas you have to control the output based on your experiences?

   ```
   ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query --commit-message --files --current-patch-set status:open project:platform/vendor/company-proprietary/code branch:master
   ```

Comment: any inputs from any body?

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the results is by last update time, and there is no option to change that.

You can limit the amount of results by using the `limit:x` parameter, or you can limit to only changes within a specific time, for example within the last week with `age:1week`.

If you need to sort by upload time, I think the only way is to load the results into a script and sort them yourself.  For that it's best to get the output as JSON by adding the `--format json` option on the command.